# Mediatr Notification not being handled

Tags: .net-6.0, mediatr

I am trying to setup mediatr notification handlers where I seem to find my self in a pickle.

I am registering the notification and the notification handler in the DI container, but whenever I fire the

```
await mediator.Publish(@event, cancellationToken);
```

it will not fire the notification handler.

Receiver

```
public class Program
{
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Information()
                    .WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger();

            Log.Logger.Information("Starting Receiver");

            IConfigurationRoot _configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddConfiguration(_configurationRoot); //add static instance of config
            serviceCollection.AddCore(null, typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName()); //add serilog etc...

            serviceCollection.AddMediatR(typeof(EventHandler<>));
            serviceCollection.AddServiceBroker();

            foreach (var service in serviceCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{service.ServiceType.FullName},{service.ImplementationType?.FullName}");
            }

            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            var stoppingToken = new CancellationToken();

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>()?.StartAsync(stoppingToken));
        }
}

public abstract class EventHandler<TNotification> : INotificationHandler<TNotification>
        where TNotification : INotification
{
        public async Task Handle(TNotification notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await HandleAsync(notification, cancellationToken);
        }

        public abstract Task HandleAsync(TNotification notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class PayloadTestEventHandler : EventHandler<PayloadTest>
{
        public override Task HandleAsync(PayloadTest notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}
```

Sender

```
public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot _configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddConfiguration(_configurationRoot);
            serviceCollection.AddCore(null, typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName());
            serviceCollection.AddServiceBroker();

            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            var publisher = serviceProvider.GetService<IPublisher>();

            publisher.Enqueue(new PayloadTest() { Payload = "test-queue-payload" });
            publisher.PublishAsync(CancellationToken.None);

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}

public class PayloadTest : IEvent
{
        public PayloadTest()
        {
        }

        public string Payload { get; set; }
}

public interface IEvent : INotification { }
```

Method that sends the notification

```
protected async Task HandleMessageAsync(Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var type = FindType(message.TypeAssembly, message.TypeName)
              ?? throw new ArgumentException(@"Could not find type {FullName} in assemblies", message.TypeName);
    var @event = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(message.Payload, type, jsonSerializerOptions);

    await mediator.Publish(@event, cancellationToken);
}
```

What I found out in my initial debugging round that when the `mediator.Publish` is being fired, the handler is registered and mediator find it but when it comes to handling it, it cannot instantiate the handler, it cannot do it and the `INotificationHandler` is not being fired.

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: What is the point of the subclass? Currently is has no real value

Comment: The subclass is there because it will be in a separate library then the implementation. This is abbreviated code so it was clear for the question